# Nancy Exception in RequestStartup

Tags: exception, nancy

I'm using Nancy to create a web api. I have a signed token that is passed in from the user to authenticate. This authentication is doen in the RequestStartup method in my own Bootstrapper. Now in some cases, for instance when I can't veryfy the signed token I would like to just be able to throw an exception and have that handled byt the OnError hanhdler in Nancy. However an exception thrown before the RequestStartup is finsihed isn't caught. The request generates a 500 error and I would like to return something else with my own error information.

I have the obvious case where I throw an exception but also possibilities of an exception being thrown in the GetIdentity() method.

I'm looking for any input in how to handle this.

```
    protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);

        pipelines.OnError.AddItemToStartOfPipeline((ctx, exception) =>
                container.Resolve<IErrorHandler>().HandleException(ctx, exception));

        var identity = container.Resolve<IAuthenticationController>().GetIdentity();
        var configuration = new StatelessAuthenticationConfiguration(_ => identity);
        StatelessAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, configuration);

        var logManager = new LogManager(context);
        pipelines.AfterRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(_ => logManager.Log());

        try
        {
            X509Certificate2 clientCert = context.Request.ClientCertificate as X509Certificate2;
            container.Resolve<ICertificateValidator>().Validate(clientCert);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new MklServerAuthenticationException(ErrorCodes.WrongOrNonexistingCertificate, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to solve the above problem and thought somebody else might like to know. Replace the line in my code above, containing the GetIdentity() call, with the following:

```
        Identity identity = null;
        try
        {
            identity = container.Resolve<IAuthenticationController>().GetIdentity(requestInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exception = new MklAuthentcationException(ErrorCodes.TokenInvalid, ex);
            context.Response = container.Resolve<IErrorHandler>().HandleException(context, exception);
            pipelines.BeforeRequest.Invoke(context, CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

I'm using the fact stated in nancy that:

> The PreRequest hook is called prior to processing a request. If a hook returns a non-null response then processing is aborted and the response provided is returned.

So by setting a response (my error in this case) on the PreRequest hook and invoking it my error is returned and execution is stopped.

Maybe not the nicest solution... If you can figure out something better please let me know.

Comment: Or rather that the above implement the BeforeRequest hook and do your stuff there.